# How many rows a normal C# window form application can load easily in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rows

I am using datagridview for data rendering in window form application. 
application is actually fetching a lot of rows and the system gets stuck and goes to not responding state. it is normally getting 100K + rows. 
How many rows a normal C# window form application can load easily in datagridview

Comment: Your speed might be effected from the number of columns and what type of data they are storing. Also there is no information about how you are rendering your data. Perhaps if you provide some additional info we can help you better. You should typically be fine with 100k rows...

Comment: You're loading data in the UI thread I believe. Offload loading to background worker/separate thread/async task and once data is completely loaded, sync it all to the UI thread and datagrid. This will remove 'not responding state', but the better solution for your problem would be to rethink the logic as users rarely need 100K+ records in single grid as this is a way too much for a human to process. How would you like to see a search engine response with 100K links at once?

Comment: It is the wrong kind of question.  You are creating UI for the benefit of a human, not to keep the OS happy.  So the real one is "how many rows can a user reasonably deal with".  About 50.  That of course never causes a perf problem.  Dumping 100K rows in his lap just produces completely unusable UI that nobody ever looks at so isn't worth considering.  Look at the way Google presents hits for a query with a million matches for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any hard limitations. This would be based on factors like the amount of resources available to the application. If you're rendering high amounts of data, you may want to consider using virutal mode.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its good idea to first of fetch 100k+ rows and show all on grid, use can use paging that will be quicker and more efficient. You can control how many records you want to fetch at once based on traffic and performance of your database.

```
@pageNumber AS INT,
@rowsPerPage AS INT,

OFFSET((@PageNumber -1) * @RowsPerPage) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;
GO
```

Read this article : 
https://10tec.com/articles/why-datagridview-slow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have analysed the application and found out that there is nothing wrong with the datagridview. it can contain 100K rows if required. 
there are some other functions that executes once the data loads which takes lot of time and puts the application in not responding state. 
Virtual mode and Paging are also good options. 
And I agree with your points that 100K rows are too much for a human to process. thats just the wastage of resources and effort. I understand that.  I am actually trying to improve someone else's application. 
Thanks guys !